# Hibernate - Fetch data using ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jersey, jax-rs

Hibernate - Fetch data using ManyToOne Relationship

Parent DeviceType Entity,

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="device_type"
 ,catalog="igedb"
 )
 public class DeviceType  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private Integer id;    
 private String deviceType;
 private String deviceCategory;
 private List<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>();

 public DeviceType() {
 }

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)    
@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}    
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(name="device_type", length=45)
public String getDeviceType() {
    return this.deviceType;
}    
public void setDeviceType(String deviceType) {
    this.deviceType = deviceType;
}    
@Column(name="device_category", length=45)
public String getDeviceCategory() {
    return this.deviceCategory;
}    
public void setDeviceCategory(String deviceCategory) {
    this.deviceCategory = deviceCategory;
}
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="deviceType")
public List<Device> getDevices() {
    return this.devices;
}    
public void setDevices(List<Device> devices) {
    this.devices = devices;
}
}
```

Child Device Entity,

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="device"
 ,catalog="igedb"
 )
 public class Device  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer id;
 private String deviceNumber;
 private DeviceType deviceType;

 public Device() {
 }

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)    
@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}    
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(name="device_number", length=45)   
public String getDeviceNumber() {
    return this.deviceNumber;
}    
public void setDeviceNumber(String deviceNumber) {
    this.deviceNumber = deviceNumber;
}
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="device_type", nullable=false)
public DeviceType getDeviceType() {
    return this.deviceType;
}
public void setDeviceType(DeviceType deviceType) {
    this.deviceType = deviceType;
}
}
```

Fetching code ,

```
deviceList = session.createQuery("FROM Device").list();
```

WebService code,

```
@GET
@Path("devices")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getDeviceList(){        
    Response response = null;
    List<Device> deviceList = null;
    try{          
        DeviceManager deviceMgr = new DeviceManager();
        deviceList = deviceMgr.getDeviceList(); 
        GenericEntity<List<Device>> list= new GenericEntity<List<Device>>      (deviceList) {};            
        response = Response.ok(list).build();         
    } catch(Exception exec){           
        response = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                                        .entity("Internal server    error").build();
    }
  return response;
}
```

While I am debugging It show records till "return response" statement.

It gives Internal Server Error 500 on WebService Response.

Can you some one please help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are going to have to post more code than this to get a definitive answer, including the code for the `Device` entity.

Comment: Added both class for entites

Answer (score 0):

It could be the lazy many to one

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
@JoinColumn(name="device_type", nullable=false)
public DeviceType getDeviceType() {
    return this.deviceType;
}
```

and

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="deviceType")
 public List<Device> getDevices() {
 return this.devices;
 }
```

when you send the query via web service you are sending a proxy to the webservice. Remotely is not possible to access the info inside the proxy and fails.

You have to fetch eager the deviceType to send the real information to the webservice.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinColumn(name="device_type", nullable=false)
public DeviceType getDeviceType() {
    return this.deviceType;
}
```

and

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="deviceType")
 public List<Device> getDevices() {
 return this.devices;
 }
```

Comment: I tried to adding FetchType as EAGER but it gives same error.

Comment: Still gives same error. I changed both side as EAGER.

Comment: Edited with more details. Added webservice part

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your list to json string then you can build your responese like this.

```
@GET
@Path("devices")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getDeviceList(){        
    Response response = null;
    List<Device> deviceList = null;
    try{          
        DeviceManager deviceMgr = new DeviceManager();
        deviceList = deviceMgr.getDeviceList(); 
        GenericEntity<List<Device>> list= new GenericEntity<List<Device>>      (deviceList) {};            
        String jsonResult = new Gson().toJson( list );        
        response = Response.ok(jsonResult).build();         
    } catch(Exception exec){           
        response = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                                        .entity("Internal server    error").build();
    }
  return response;
}
```